# Поиск гамильтонова цикла в графе

Tags: математика, алгоритм, графы

Какой на данный момент самый быстрый алгоритм поиска гамильтонова цикла в небольшом графе (~ 50-70 вершин)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё зависит от ваших требований: к примеру, имеет ли ваш граф какие-то структурные особенности, готовы ли вы работать с рандомизированным алгоритмом (т.е., алгоритмом, который с небольшой вероятностью может дать неправильный ответ) и т.д. Не претендуя на полный обзор литературы по теме, упомяну несколько известных результатов. Я не знаю, есть ли у вас доступ к журналам, если нет - дайте мейл и я всё вышлю.

- Если ваш граф планарный и 4-связный, то задача решается за линейное время ([Чиба, Нишизеки 1989](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0196677489900126)), а если просто планарный то за О(c^\sqrt(n)), где константа c не зависит от графа ([Дейнеко, Клинц, Вугингер 2006](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167637705000763))
- Если ваш граф т.н. cocomparability graph (интересно, как это по-русски?), то задача полиномиальна ([Деогун, Штейнер 1994](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0097539791200375))
- Если вы готовы работать с рандомизированным алгоритмом, то O(1.657^n); для двудольных графов  O(1.414^n) ([Бьёрклунд 2010](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=5670820))
- Если степень вершин не превышает 3, то задача всё равно в NP, а лучший алгоритм - O(1.251^n) ([Ивама, Накашима 2007](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-540-73545-8_13))

Comment: Ого, вот это теоретическая подготовка!